# How to handle nullable string as a function parameter

Tags: c#, string, function

I have function with parameters as given below.

```
public void myfunction(int a, string b){}
```

Can we call this function by passing only first parameter and second parameter is optional(nullable string)?

```
myfunction(5);
```

If yes then how.

Comment: i am using visual studio 2015..

Comment: @bigyanshr - `string?` does not compile.  `string` is already nullable and cannot be used as a type in `Nullable<T>`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually, your question is a little bit confusing because by the term `nullable` in the title, meantime you are looking for a method having [default parameters/Optional parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx). which can be written like the following:

```
public void myfunction(int a, string b = ""){}
```

So that you can call like this `myfunction(5);` or like `myfunction(5,null);` or even this: `myfunction(5,"Something");`

Comment: It won't even compile :)   The message will be:  The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Nullable<T>'

Comment: @MaksimSimkin : thank you For correcting me, I have updated the answer

Answer (score 4):

just overload the function as follows:

```
public void myfunction(int a, string b)
{
   //do stuff
}

public void myfunction(int a)
{
  myfunction(a,string.empty);
}
```

then call

```
myFuntion(5);
```

Note: It's best practice to use string.empty instead of null so have shown that in my example.

Comment: Why would someone use this, and not the accepted answer? I see no use for this ugly solution.

Comment: One reason would be if you were supporting a legacy .net application as the accepted answer's syntax was not available until c# 4.